# VB.NET resize and crop images

Tags: vb.net, vsto, image-resizing

i have a VSTO for powerpoint and want to resize images so they are the same size as the slide. a sample image i have is 1000x300 and the slide is 960x540. so this is the code i have:

```
_W=960
_H=540

Dim img As Image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(file1)
OldRect = New RectangleF(233, 0, 533, 300) ' calculated values to crop left and right 
NewRect = New RectangleF(0, 0, _W, _H)

Dim bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(img, _W, _H)
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
g.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
g.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
g.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
g.DrawImage(img, NewRect, OldRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel) 
img.Save(file2, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

but when i look at file2 it's the same 1000x300 file as the original. what am i missing here?

Comment: `img.Save(file2, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)`  you are saving the original image object not the new one.  you are also leaking resources

Comment: afaik the g.DrawImage rewrites the content of img as it uses it as a source and as a destination. the first NewRect should tell it the new size and the OldRect the part of the original image.

Or is that the part i'm missing and doesn't it work like that?

Comment: btw, i call img.Dispose() before exiting the function. the rest should be GC'd when i exit the function?

Comment: nope.  `g.Drawimage` draws the contents of `img` to the new bitmap object `bmp`.  After all, the `Graphics` object was created from that.  *Everything* which implements a `Dispose` method should be enclosed in a `Using` block.

Comment: ow? so if i can get the bmp to Save() i'd have the part of the picture that i want? that's not quite what microsoft docs had me believe. i'll give that a try..

Answer (score 0):

@plutonix; you're spot on. i was under the wrong impression that DrawImage would replace the image it was offered. but saving the bitmap the graphics object was created with produced the intended image.

```
bmp.Save(file2, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

works perfect. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The answer posted here is good but there is one major problem of quality that need to be addressed. In most cased you have to Crop Image and Maintain the Quality so in that regard, I have improved the crop feature of a sample and posted below is the link. This demo is in VB.NET but you can easily understand the concept and make adjustments.

http://www.mediafire.com/file/70rmlpcdjyxo8gc/ImageCroppingDemo_-_Maintain_Image_Quality.zip/file

**CODES For Cropping (VB.NET)**

```
Dim cropX As Integer
Dim cropY As Integer
Dim cropWidth As Integer
Dim cropHeight As Integer
Dim oCropX As Integer
Dim oCropY As Integer
Dim cropBitmap As Bitmap
Dim Loadedimage As Image

Public cropPen As Pen
Public cropPenSize As Integer = 1 '2
Public cropDashStyle As Drawing2D.DashStyle = Drawing2D.DashStyle.Solid
Public cropPenColor As Color = Color.Yellow

Private Sub crobPictureBox_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles crobPictureBox.MouseDown
    Try

        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then

            cropX = e.X
            cropY = e.Y

            cropPen = New Pen(cropPenColor, cropPenSize)
            cropPen.DashStyle = DashStyle.DashDotDot
            Cursor = Cursors.Cross

        End If
        crobPictureBox.Refresh()
    Catch exc As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
Dim tmppoint As Point
Private Sub crobPictureBox_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles crobPictureBox.MouseMove
    Try

        If crobPictureBox.Image Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then

            crobPictureBox.Refresh()
            cropWidth = e.X - cropX
            cropHeight = e.Y - cropY
            crobPictureBox.CreateGraphics.DrawRectangle(cropPen, cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight)
        End If
        ' GC.Collect()

    Catch exc As Exception

        If Err.Number = 5 Then Exit Sub
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub crobPictureBox_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles crobPictureBox.MouseUp
    Try
        Cursor = Cursors.Default
        Try

            If cropWidth < 1 Then
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Dim smallWidthPercentage As Single = (cropWidth / crobPictureBox.Width) * 100
            Dim smallHeightPercentage As Single = (cropHeight / crobPictureBox.Height) * 100

            Dim smallXPercentage As Single = (cropX / crobPictureBox.Width) * 100
            Dim smallYPercentage As Single = (cropY / crobPictureBox.Height) * 100

            smallHeightPercentage += 10
            smallYPercentage -= 10

            Dim Widthdifference As Integer = Loadedimage.Width - crobPictureBox.Width
            Dim HeightDifference As Integer = Loadedimage.Height - crobPictureBox.Height

            Dim rect As Rectangle
            rect = New Rectangle((smallXPercentage / 100) * Loadedimage.Width, (smallYPercentage / 100) * Loadedimage.Height, (smallWidthPercentage / 100) * Loadedimage.Width, (smallHeightPercentage / 100) * Loadedimage.Height)

            Dim bit As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Loadedimage, Loadedimage.Width, Loadedimage.Height)

            cropBitmap = New Bitmap(Loadedimage, (smallWidthPercentage / 100) * Loadedimage.Width, (smallHeightPercentage / 100) * Loadedimage.Height)

            Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(cropBitmap)
            g.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
            g.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
            g.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
            g.DrawImage(bit, 0, 0, rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
            PreviewPictureBox.Image = cropBitmap

        Catch exc As Exception
        End Try
    Catch exc As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```